# Techniques for keyframe simulation using SVG

Tags: animation, graphics, svg, simulation

I want to create a keyframe simulation using SVG, the idea is that the objects in the animation/simulation have particular positions (or line lengths) at particular times. So for example, I may have divided the 1-minute simulation into 60 1-second intervals. I want to do three things:

(a) be able to play the 60-frame simulation frame by frame

(b) be able to select any frame by clicking on a frame button (imagine 60 small rectangles at the bottom of the screen, each representing a particular frame)

(c) be able to step forwards or backwards from a given frame

What would be good ways to do this using SVG?

For example, imagine I have two circles moving around. At each time T (from 1 to 60) each of the circles has a location and radius and visibility (it might be invisible during one or more frames). How do I structure the SVG file?

Note that I would like to avoid using Javascript (ECMA) to do this. I am hoping for a pure SVG solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear you might be out of luck doing this without JavaScript.  In theory, it's perfectly possible to do with SMIL animation, unfortunately support is not so good or at least very inconsistent.  If you want to try anyway or if you're happy to make it work in a specific browser, [this might give you a starting point](http://jsbin.com/UwAxoVON/1/edit):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="110" height="230">
  <!-- some moving circle -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50">
    <set id="a0" attributeName="cy" to="50"  begin="start.click; r0.click"/>
    <set id="a1" attributeName="cy" to="75"  begin="a0.begin+1s; r1.click"/>
    <set id="a2" attributeName="cy" to="100" begin="a1.begin+1s; r2.click"/>
    <set id="a3" attributeName="cy" to="125" begin="a2.begin+1s; r3.click"/>
  </circle>
  <!-- Rects to address certain frames -->
  <g fill="#d44">
    <rect id="r0" width="20" height="20" y="180"/>
    <rect id="r1" width="20" height="20" y="180" x="30"/>
    <rect id="r2" width="20" height="20" y="180" x="60"/>
    <rect id="r3" width="20" height="20" y="180" x="90"/>
  </g>
  <!-- Play button-->
  <polygon id="start" points="40,210 70,220 40,230" fill="#6d6"/>
</svg>
```

This attempts to solve your points (a) and (b), but I think it only works as intended in classic non-Blink Opera.  I'm not sure whether [FakeSmile](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/) can help you get more consistent behavior.

Comment: @TylerDurden Would be great if you could post an answer of your own if you can improve on my answer.

Comment: This works really well, your "r0.click" syntax is what I was looking for.